# Using Mix Shaders for Texture Paint Layers, Black Colours Do Not Show

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders, texture-painting

I'm trying to set up a layering system like in Photoshop using Mix Shaders for when I texture paint in Blender. But when I use a black colour on the 2nd/top layer, it doesn't show up. It acts as an eraser. Black will show on the 1st/bottom layer, though. Every other colour shows fine. I've also tried the same approach with a Mix RGB node, but still black does not show.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After messing around with it for a bit, I figured it out. The Alpha of the second layer needs to go into the Factor of the Mix RGB node.

[image]

Comment: I think the original problem was that you were putting two color outputs into a mix shader node.